# Object of infinitive when it becomes a substantive?

Tags: noun, infinitive, objects

I believe in zu+inf construction we can put object of verb:

> "ich bevorzuge ein Haus zu bauen"
>   "ich bevorzuge an Sie zu denken"

What about when they are Substantiv? correct?

> "Nach einem Hause Bauen waren wir müde"
>   "Das an Sie Denken ist schön für mich"

Comment: _"Nach einem Hause Bauen waren wir müde"_ isn't proper German.

Comment: It should be *"Nach dem Hausbau(en) waren wir müde."* or *"Nach dem Bauen des Hauses waren wir müde."* Furthermore, it is *"das An-Sie-Denken"*, i.e., it must be hyphenated because it is a single noun.

Answer (score 2):

We must differentiate between simple objects and objects with a preposition.

A **simple object** becomes a genitive:

> "ich bevorzuge ein Haus zu bauen"

becomes

> Ich bevorzuge das Bauen eines Hauses.

Alternatively, often you can use a compound:

> Ich bevorzuge (den) Hausbau.

This is terser and I would prefer it if the compound is a frequently used word in and of itself (for example Hausbau).

When you have a **preposition**, a genitive construction does usually not convey the same meaning. Fortunately, you can link two nouns with a preposition.
Therefore,

> "ich bevorzuge an Sie zu denken"

becomes

> Ich bevorzuge das Denken an sie

Mind however that this particular sentence sounds very unnatural, albeit grammatically correct.

Some additional remarks:

1. There are complicated rules on commas in infinitive groups. If the infinitive has an object, I advise to set a comma after the main verb.
2. Sentences with many substantives are hard to read. Many style guides recommend to use verbs instead.
3. @datafiddler: "Singen  üben" can also be written non-capitalized, i.e. "singen üben". See [here](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueben_wiederholen_lernen_aneignen).

Answer (score -1):

zu + infinitive is rather common, e.g. with verbs indicating a plan.  [see here](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/verben/infinitiv)

> Ich versuche zu singen

BTW: With other verbs, you don't need/use the "zu"

> Ich höre dich singen

You can add an object:

> Ich versuche Lieder zu singen

If this object and thus the whole infinitive part is more complex, you need a comma and the infinitive becomes a partial sentence.

> Ich wurde gefragt, Gershwin's "Summer Time" zu singen.

You can also see it opposite: There are some simple forms, allowing to omit the comma nowadays!

[Nach der neuen deutschen Rechtschreibung kann man bei einem einfachen Infinitv das Komma auch weglassen, wenn der Satz dadurch nicht missverständlich wird.](https://www.rechtschreibuebungen.com/zeichensetzung/komma-bei-infinitivgruppen-klickuebung.html)

Now there's a construct called "Substantivierter Infinitiv", which treats the infinitive as a noun. It's possible to add an article then. (This helps to distinguish the two, because e.g. capitalization is different, and the "zu" disappears)

> Ich höre ein Singen
>
> Ich übe Singen

When you think about objects, you then have here two nouns with their flavors of combining them to a single noun in German.

> Ich liebe das Schlager Singen
>
> Ich liebe [das] Schlagersingen

As soon as it becomes more complex, it comes to a limit, however. And you should simply avoid it.